# Logging 3-phase power

Tags: resistors, generator, three-phase, delta

I need to measure and log power, and I want to do it mostly correctly.  I would greatly appreciate a listing of the errors I have made in my method.
I want to measure (and log) the power output of a small 3-phase generator.

Components:

200 w, 24 v, 200 rpm - 3 phase delta generator

200 w buck/boost mppt controller

-10 v to 10 v DATAQ DI-149 data logger

Three 2-ohm, 25 w. resistors

I think logging the voltage is not a problem: measure across the 75k of a 75k/91k pair.  The DI-149 can internally convert to rms and log same.

The DI-149 measures the 20 v. span in increments of 0.02 v.  My plan was to put a 2 ohm resistor between each of the 3 outputs of the generator and the inputs of the MPPT and log the rms voltage drop and convert to current.

I will multiply the rms voltage and calculated current to arrive at power (and then throw in I^2 R to account for the power lost in the resistor?)?

I would be satisfied with +/- 10% accuracy.  Is this going to get me there?

Comment: No. Power is not calculated by multiplying voltage with current. Also your current sensing resistor wastes way too much energy. Why not just buy a logger that logs power directly, or a power meter and a logger and connect them together?

Comment: Multiplying Vrms with Irms does not give you power in Watts - it gives you apparent power in VA. For each sample period you need to multiply the V and I samples to get a power value and then rms *that*.

Comment: @brhans I'm afraid power value samples need to be averaged not RMS'ed.

Comment: RMS power requires that each V*I is done in real time or  filtered and sampled subcycle  time then averaged between readings.

Comment: but if V is reasonably constant over say 10 cycles then you can compute Rms V and I separately but you must measure the RMS phase difference to extract real power from apparent power.  So you see a true RMS meter from Fluke is much better.  To my knowledge DATAQ has no builtin way to compute V*I(t) real power only Vrms.

Comment: Use three current transformers to get a nearly lossless and isolated current measurement on each phase.

Comment: I researched power meter datalogger before. I found ICP power meter can log power data, single phase or three phase into computer database. They have different protocols to choose from like CAN, modbus. Hope it helps. [https://www.icpdas-usa.com/intelligentpowermetersboards.html](https://www.icpdas-usa.com/intelligentpowermetersboards.html?r=steve)

Answer (score 1):

> I will multiply the rms voltage and calculated current to arrive at power (and then throw in I^2 R to account for the power lost in the resistor?)?

AC power is more complicated. If you multiply like DC, P=U*I, then you know **S**, the apparent power in **VA**. You have to multiply **S** with the phase angle **φ** to get the Real Power **P** in Watts.

I suggest you read the [AC power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power) wiki page, and use those formula's to compute your values.

Since you can sample all required 6 channels (voltage and current per phase) at 10 Khz you should be able to get at least some accurate results. However, your buck/boost might cause an inaccuracy in the measurement due to distortion.

You will be in for some serious software work though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know how true power is measured, and you cannot use a true RMS voltmeter to do this, I would suggest you have the wrong datalogger for this simple job.

Perhaps you can rent a Fluke [**1736**](http://media.fluke.com/documents/FEAp____oheng0200.pdf).